# Google geocoder returning short_name as long_name for states

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoding-api

I'm using the google javascript geocoder and short_name for state had previously been correct i.e. short_name: "nh", long_name: "New Hampshire". I'm noticing now that i'm seeing "New Hampshire" for both long_name and short_name. Is this a bug or something that changed that I need to update?

Answer (score 5):

This is ongoing issue on the Google side. It was reported in the public issue tracker by several users:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37479392

You can add your comments in the public issue with examples of your requests and star it to add your vote.

**UPDATE**

The issue was resolved by Google on April 27, 2017.